# Wordpress - Membership: Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment

Tags: wordpress, civimember

first things first, my setup:

- PHP 7.0.28
- Wordpress 4.9
- CiviCRM 5.8.0

So, I don't get my membership registration process to work, which is very frustrating because of the poor feedback of the system. After submitting the form is says:

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.

Zur Anfangsseite zurück."

In "ConfigAndLog" I got:

```
Dec 12 15:43:15  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => 
    [code] => 
)


Dec 12 15:43:15  [info] $backTrace = #0 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1201): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
#2 /qqq/wp/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/gdpr.php(259): CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Contribute_DAO_Contribution", NULL, "contact_id", "trxn_id")
#3 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(274): gdpr_civicrm_buildForm("CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou))
#4 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(155): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:5), "civicrm_buildForm", 2, "CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#5 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(90): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(2, "CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_buildForm")
#6 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_buildForm", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#7 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_buildForm", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#8 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_buildForm", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#9 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(164): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_buildForm", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#10 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(425): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:2), "CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_buildForm")
#11 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(618): CRM_Utils_Hook::buildForm("CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou))
#12 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#13 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou), "display")
#14 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou), "display")
#15 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#16 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#17 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#18 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#19 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1240): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#20 /qqq/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(365): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#21 /qqq/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#22 /qqq/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(FALSE, (Array:1))
#23 /qqq/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#24 /qqq/wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php(726): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#25 /qqq/wp/wp-includes/functions.php(960): WP->main("")
#26 /qqq/wp/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#27 /qqq/wp/index.php(18): require("/qqq/wp/wp-blog-header.php")
#28 {main}
```

which is not helpful at all, at least not for me. So maybe this is my most important question, how to improve the feedback/error message of the system? Or do you have any idea how to make the error go away in the first place and make the membership process work?

[image: Profile Page]
[image: Amount Page - Why is the Tab grayed out btw?]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backtrace shows the GDPR extension is involved.  Try temporarily disabling the GDPR extension and see if your membership form works.  Make sure that the GDPR extension is the latest release and check it is fully configured.  I have seen issues in an earlier version when the extension is installed but not configured.

If the problem only occurs when GDPR is enabled and you have done the steps above, try logging an issue on the extension's site.